# SharePoint Foundation 2013: XML declaration issue for my custom task form

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, custom

I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2013 and I have a sequential list workflow, I'd like to create a custom task form using my custom content type already created in visual studio which the attribute Inherits is set at FALSE, but it seems i can't read my XML declaration.

```
<XmlDocuments>
  <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
    <FormUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
      <Display>_layouts/STAProcessConge/AprouveTaskForm.aspx</Display>
      <Edit>_layouts/STAProcessConge/AprouveTaskForm.aspx</Edit>
      <New>_layouts/STAProcessConge/AprouveTaskForm.aspx</New>
    </FormUrls>
  </XmlDocument>
</XmlDocuments>
```